# MongoDB - Storage Engine error

Tags: mongodb

I am getting this error. Did not change anything at my end. Till last week everything worked fine.
''''
Detected data files in /data/db created by storage engine 'wiredTiger'. The configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'., terminating
2017-06-06T16:36:06.391-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to start the server with the 'mmapv1' storage engine, but it is pointing to a data directory containing wiredtiger storage files. Either the files, or the directory, or the server config must have been changed by somebody or something; I suggest you look through the server logs to try and identify how and when.